# Aprovacoes, reprovacoes e media da sala-Java

Tags: java

Preciso receber 30 notas e devolver o numero de aprovacoes, reprovacoes e a media da sala.
Tentei o seguinte:

```
public class notas { 
public static int aprovacoes;
public static int reprovacoes;
public static int recs;
public static double total;

public static void main(String []args){
    double notas[] = new double [30];

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Digite todas as notas: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < notas.length; i++){
        notas[i] = input.nextDouble();
    }
    System.out.println("numero de aprovados: "+aprovacoes);
    System.out.println("numero de reprovados: "+reprovacoes);
    System.out.println("numero de recs: "+recs);
    System.out.println("media da sala: "+(total/30));
}
    public static void resultadoSala(double [] notas){
        for(int i = 0; i < notas.length; i++){
            if(notas[i] >= 5){
                aprovacoes++;
            }
            else if(notas[i] <= 3){
                reprovacoes++;
            }
            else{
                recs++;
            }
        }
    }
    public static double mediaSala(double []notas){
        for(int i = 0; i < notas.length; i++){
            total += notas[i];  
        }
        return total;
    }
```

}

Porém, apos compilar o codigo e inserir as notas, todas as saídas ficaram iguais a zero.
O que eu devo fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Ficou faltando chamar os métodos `resultadoSala` e `mediaSala`:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    double notas[] = new double [30];

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Digite todas as notas: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < notas.length; i++){
        notas[i] = input.nextDouble();
    }

    resultadoSala(notas);
    mediaSala(notas);

    System.out.println("numero de aprovados: "+aprovacoes);
    System.out.println("numero de reprovados: "+reprovacoes);
    System.out.println("numero de recs: "+recs);
    System.out.println("media da sala: "+(total/30));
}
```